# Adding Transition to text on load

Tags: css, animation, transition

I am trying to add transition to text on my site such that when the page is loaded, the opacity of "Hello" changes from 0 to 1 in the first second and the  opacity of the text "Name" changes from 0 to 1 in the next second. I tried to use transition but it would work only with hover not with load. I tried keyframes and animation but that does work only in the designated time and the page loads with a default opacity of 1.
The requirement is this:
**Hello (appears in the first second with a transition)**
**Name (appears in the next second with transition)**
Initially both having opacity 0.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is the code you've tried? Are you open to JavaScript? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use forwards animation.

```css
.hello,
.name {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear forwards;
}

.name {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
<div class="name">there</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JS, you can wait until everything is loaded before your animations fire and you can have a fallback if the user doesn't have JS enabled.

If you just use `animation` without JS, the animations will start before your page is loaded and the user may not see the animation.

```js
// WAIT UNTIL THE WINDOW IS FULLY LOADED
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // GET THE BODY OBJECT
  let body = document.querySelector("body");
  // ADD THE CLASS TO THE BODY
  body.classList.add('js-loaded')
});
```

```css
@keyframes opacity {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* IF THE USER DOESN'T HAVE JS */

h1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

p {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* IF THE USER HAS JS */

body.js-loaded h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: opacity 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body.js-loaded p {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: opacity 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>
      This is your header.
    </h1>
    <p>
      Eleifend nec eget. Id massa quis eu vitae elit. Bibendum interdum semper. Donec libero duis.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```